# Where can I find a paste service with (client side) encryption?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to:

- paste / edit a text snippet online
- encrypt that snippet in my browser
- store that snippet online
- tell some of my folks about the URL to the snippet AND the passphrase

are there services like that available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [LockMyStuff](https://www.lockmystuff.com/index.php) It also give you some options like max permitted users, time to expire and keep track of access to the message

Answer (score 1):

I found https://defuse.ca/pastebin.htm to be pretty useful and working well.

> This pastebin encrypts your post with a 128 bit equivalent random code
>   which is included in the paste URL. The URL code is hashed using
>   SHA256 into a key for AES-256 in CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) mode. The
>   only way anyone will see your paste is if they have the URL. So only
>   share the paste URL with people you trust, and your data will be 100%
>   private. We've also setup a robots.txt file telling Google and other
>   search engines not to index the contents of the pastebin. If we get a
>   court order to decrypt a post, we will not be able to comply.
>
> You also have the option of encrypting your text with client-side
>   encryption. This is much more secure because the encryption and
>   decryption happen right in your browser using JavaScript. That way, we
>   never get the chance to see the unencrypted data nor the password used
>   to encrypt it. When you use client-side encryption, your password gets
>   hashed with SHA256 into a 256 bit key for the AES block cipher, which
>   is used to encrypt the text in CBC mode. A random 256 bit salt and a
>   random initialization vector are provided by our server's CSPRNG
>   (Cryptographically Secure Pseudorandom Number Generator).
>
> The data is always sent to Defuse Cyber-Security through a secure,
>   AES-256 encrypted, SSL/TLS connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at www.codebarrel.com? I think it has everything you posted you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [cryptob.in](https://cryptob.in). Client side encryption with AES 256-bit. You can choose between different expiration times. The encryption key is generated automatically, no need to enter one. They have syntax coloring and a discussion option. It’s also https (SSL).

Comment: Are you affiliated with cryptob.in? If so, you should disclose it.

Comment: No. Just found it while looking for an encypted pastebin.