# Is there a simple paste-to-save app?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to quickly paste snippets of text and links to be saved automatically. The key is fast saving, not viewing saved content. Private-by-default is a must, sharing capabilities are plus. Any suggestions?

Comment: Save forever, long enough to share, a month, a year?

Comment: The term you are looking for is called a pastebin

Comment: also see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/140/where-can-i-find-a-paste-service-with-client-side-encryption

Comment: @rchern forever

Comment: @phwd Oh, thanks, that' exactly what I was looking for! Found a great list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_pastebins Edit: Could you make your comment an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is called a [pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin). [re:comments]

Answer (score 1):

Paste stuff to your friends:

- http://friendpaste.com/

Another *app* is github's gist, which has a command line interface, too:

- [http://defunkt.github.com/gist/](http://gist.github.com)

  ```
  $ man gist
  gist can be used to create gists on gist.github.com from the command line. 
  There are two primary methods of creating gists.


  If standard input is supplied, it will be used as the content of the 
  new gist. If FILE is provided, the content of that file will be used 
  to create the gist.


  Once your gist is successfully created, the URL will be copied to 
  your clipboard. If you are on OS X, gist will open the gist in your 
  browser, too.
  ```

`gist`example:

```
$ echo "This gist was saved via command-line ..." | gist
http://gist.github.com/476709
```

See the result at: http://gist.github.com/476709

Private gists are also available.

Answer (score 1):

**The best tool for this is**: http://notepad.cc

> [Notepad.cc http://img2.pict.com/22/49/78/3794650/0/1279198726.jpg](http://img2.pict.com/22/49/78/3794650/0/1279198726.jpg)

A newer site that is similar to http://notepad.cc is http://wrttn.in

Answer (score 0):

Zotero Plugin for Firefox,  Saves text, pages, files  quickly and has the ability to share things as well.